# Is this array comprehension correct?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, list-comprehension

I have a 2 dimension array and i wan't to modify it to use it in a function.

One of the elements must be a link for an html code.
So I wonder that i can make this kind of conditional transformation.

> 1. The array is 2 dimensional arrayName[i][j]. i is looped outside my doubt.
> 2. Every element goes to the new array except one. (length - 2 position)
> 3. The exceptional item must be transformed in an html link.

I'm trying something like:

```
 [for( j = 0, j < arrayName[0].length, j++ )
  if (j <> arrayName[i].lenght - 2 ) arrayName[i][j] else "link things"
  ]
```

also i try:

```
[for (j=0, j<arrayName[i].length,j++)
 function(j){if (j <> arrayName[i].length - 2 ){
             return arrayName[i][j];}
             else{ return "link thing";})}
 ]
```

of course "link thing" should be an string:

```
'<a href=\"'+ array[i][j] + '\">Link.</a>'
```

But i don't pass the debug.

Comment: Indent your code, it saves puppies' lives. Also, full code please. What you're doing here is also very weird, working inside of [ and skipping all brackets.

Comment: id didn't indented because this is suposed to be in one line. Some documentation i've been reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects **Array comprehensions.**

Comment: You've spelled `length` wrong (`lenght`, above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why loop through the array items at all if you know the position you need to change?  Why not just directly change the value of the item at index `length - 2`?

So something like:

```
var arrayName = [...]; // your multi-dimesional array

// modify arrayName in place
for (i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) { // iteration over outer array
    var targetIndex = arrayName[i].length - 2;
    arrayName[i][targetIndex] = '<a href=\"'+ array[i][targetIndex] + '\">Link.</a>';
}
```

Comment: Because it's relative, I make the suposition that de previous to the last item [length-2] is the one that must be a link. But the array may vary it's length.

Comment: @user2209264 So?  That still doesn't mean you need to iterate over the entire array.  You know the length of the array and you know the position of the item you are interested relative to the end of the array.  Just access it directly, do not iterate here when there is absolutely no need to!  What if your array was 1000 items long?  Wouldn't you rather directly access item at index 998 rather than iterate through each until you reach the next to last one? You should have a time complexity of O(1) and you are making into a complexity of O(n) meaning performance degrades linearly with array size

Comment: Oh, I should explain: I get the array parsing a csv file. So, if I change the columns in the csv the array will be different, and the code must work with that. I need to get a new array with everything as it is, except the transformed item.

Comment: @user2209264 Yes. But you already have the array in memory when you are performing this action (Otherwise you wouldn't know the length of the array at all).  How you got the array into memory makes no difference here at all.

Comment: so you are saying that I only should define a function wich changes that element and nothing more.

Comment: @user2209264 Yes.  There is no need to even touch the other elements in the array if you are not modifying them at all. See my updated answer for example.  Note I do not iterate over inner arrays at all.

Comment: @user2209264 You might even go a step further and also simply update the value as you are loading it into `arrayName` (not sure how this is done currently).  This would prevent you from having to iterate over `arrayName` outer array at all after reading it into memory.

Comment: I actually used a generic code for importing csv and making the parse. I didn't want to change it to keep it with generic use.

Answer (score 0):

You an use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
for ( var i = 0, len = arrayName.length; i < len; ++i ) {
    var link = '<a href=\"'+ arrayName[i].splice(arrayName[i].length-2, 1)[0] + '\">Link.</a>';
    /* do somethink with link */
}
```

And maybe you should check if `arrayName[i].length-2 >= 0` to avoid possible errors.